# Selecting the element value using XSLT when the string matches the previous element value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to get the value of B from the following XML when element A matches a certain string.

```
<Names>
    <Name>
        <A>Hans</A>
        <B>Peter</B>
    </Name>
    <Name>
        <A>Peter</A>
        <B>Pan</B>
    </Name>
</Names>
```

I tried a lot but nothing worked.

```
<NameABC><xsl:value-of select="Names/Name/[A='Peter']"/@B /></NameABC>
```

I hope someone can help me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
select="Names/Name[A='Hans']/B/text()"
```

Answer (score -1):

Your current path is invalid. It contains a parse error (quote) and you have a predicate without a tag name.

Also, you're treating `B` as though it's a *child* of `A` rather than a sibling. Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Names/Name[A='Peter']/@B/text()" />
```

Comment: thanks. but unfortunatley I'm still getting the following error:

Axis step attribute::attribute(Q{}B) cannot be used here: the context item is not a node

Comment: Dang... I forgot `/text()`. Glad you got the issue sorted anyway.